# Adding a list on top of a list

Tags: lyx

How do I "stack" a list on top of another? I'm trying to answer questions with multiple sections, something like "question 1 (a)(i), (a)(ii), (a)(iii), (b)(i), b(ii), b(iii)... question 2:..." and so on. However, on Lyx, I'm struggling to stack the lists on top of one another. Here's an example of what I mean done in google docs:

[image: example]

Comment: Use nested ```enumerate``` environments

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that in Lyx? Do I add it to my preambles? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: press tab to increase the depth of an item, and shift+tab to decrease it.

Comment: A useful technical term that might be helpful to you when searching is "nesting". You want to "nest" an enumerate inside an enumerate. This is covered in Help > User Guide, Section 3.3.6 Lists.

Comment: At the right of 4 list buttons (enumerate, etc.) you have 2 buttons to increase depth and decrease depth. Also, if you are starting the item "`2.`",  for instance,  that item can be nested as `(a)`, with `Tab` and `(b)` can be changed to  "i" (3rd level)  in the same way , whereas `Shift+Tab` make the opposite.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, all of you!

Comment: @Fran I propose that you copy/paste your comment as an answer.